# importing app templates and static files to other templates Django

Tags: html, css, django

I want to place my `gallery.html` and `gallery.css` inside my `base.html`. I've ran `collectstatic` and `runserver` but the gallery.css and html cannot be located when I inspect it with chrome dev tools. Only the base.html and css are to be found and displayed.

Here is a brief structure of my project:

```
/proj
   /gallery
      /static
         /css
            gallery.css
      /templates
         gallery.html
   /proj
   /templates
      base.html
   /static
      /css
         base.css
```

base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- Base css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/base.css" %}">

  </head>
  <body class="background">
    <div class="wrapper">   
      {% block content %}
        <!-- content here-->
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

gallery.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}

<!-- container for photos-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/masonry.pkgd.minjs" %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/gallery.css" %}">
<div class="gallery-container">
    dsfsdfdsfdsf
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

gallery.css:

```
.gallery-container {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

base.css

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}
.background {
    background-color:#b0a0e6;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'websiteAssets'))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)     

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'home/templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'gallery/templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'contact/templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'aboutme/templates'),
)
```

Comment: You have `websiteAssets` directory configured in `STATIC_ROOT`, but I don't see it in the project structure..

Comment: @alecxe its actually outside my project. I was told its good practice to do so for production

Answer (score 1):

With the line `{% static 'css/gallery.css' %}` you are trying to get the static file gallery.css located in the directory 'css' but this directory doesn't exist as gallery is put in just the directory 'static' and not 'static/css'. Try doing it by `{% static 'gallery.css' %}` or creating a directory 'css' in static and putting gallery.css in it.

Comment: I would like to keep the static files and css within the app folder. How would I do this so that the HTML file would know to look inside my gallery app or any other app specifically?

Comment: I made a mistake in writing the structure of the project. The app is in fact gallery/static/css/gallery.css

Answer (score 1):

Old question and I'm sure you've either figured out a solution or moved on, but you need to add:

```
{% load static %}
```

in your `gallery.html` beneath the `{% extends 'base.html' %}`. Django templates require you to load static files on any template that you are using them in regardless if they are included in a template that you are extending from. See [here](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/templates_static.html) for a better reference.